# Unauthorized error while accessing an API using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api, http-status-code-401

I am new dev in react js.

I was trying to post data from my registration form to an API.

It worked once and when I try doing it again I am encountering this problem.

> Error:401
> {error: "unauthorized_client", error_description: "Unable to create user", error_uri: null}
> error: "unauthorized_client"
> error_description: "Unable to create user"

The code is below:
Register.js

```js
import React  from "react";

export class Register extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
    super();
    this.state={ nickname:'', email:'',password:'' }
        }
    
    handleChange = event =>{
        this.setState({ [event.target.name]:event.target.value })
    }
    handleSubmit = event =>{
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("Username : " + this.state.nickname)
        console.log("User Email :" + this.state.email)
        console.log("Password:"+this.state.password)
        const url =*******************
        const data = {  nickname:this.state.nickname,email:this.state.email,password:this.state.password }
        fetch(url, { method: 'POST', // or ‘PUT’
            body: new URLSearchParams("nickname=this.state.nickname&email=this.state.email&password=this.state.password"), // data can be `string` or {object}!
        
           // headers:{ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' ,'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',}
            })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))
            .then(response => console.log('Success:', response));
        console.log(data)
        
         }
    render(){
         return(
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        Nickname:
            <input type="text" name="nickname" onChange={this.handleChange} /><br/>
        Email:
            <input type="email" name="email" onChange={this.handleChange} /><br/>
        Password:
            <input type="password" name="password" onChange={this.handleChange} /><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Register" /> </form> 
    ); 
        }
        }
```

Please go through the code and let me know if I have missed something.

Comment: That "unauthorized client" hint probably means you have to pass auth details with the request to authenticate your client. Maybe you accidentally removed a required header, cookies are expired, or you have to configure your `fetch` call to send cookies.

Comment: @Jacob Thank you for your suggestion. I have tried correcting everything but still facing the same issue. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.